# If $ax + by = 8$, what is $\operatorname{gcd}(a, b)$?

Tags: proof-writing

Our instructor has given us this problem:

> If $ax + by = 8$, what is $\operatorname{gcd}(a, b)$?

I'm confused. Is it not just $8$? Since, say, $\operatorname{gcd}(a, b) = n$, so there must exist some $x, y$ such that $n= ax + by$.

Do I need to prove that?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that $a,b,x,y\in\Bbb Z$, the only thing that can be guaranteed is that $\gcd(a,b)$ divides $8$.

For example, for $a=b=1$, we have
$$4a+4b=8$$
or
$$5a+3b=8$$

What Bezout's identity says is:

> If $\gcd(a,b)=d$ then there exist two integers $x,y$ such that $ax+by=d$.

and what you have wrongly applied is

> If there exist two integers $x,y$ such that $ax+by=d$ then $d=\gcd(a,b)$.

The following statement is true, nevertheless:

> If $ax+by=d$ then $\gcd(a,b)$ divides $d$.

Comment: So it would just be anything that divides 8?

Comment: Yes, indeed it would.